# Efficiently highlight known math macros in AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, syntax-highlighting

I am using AucTeX to write LaTeX and I have fontification enabled. The highlighting of marcos works but while macros like **\begin** are highlighted using *font-lock-keyword-face* all math macros (**\sum**, **\leq** to mention a few) are highlighed using *font-lock-sedate-face* that is reserved for ``unknown'' macros.

On the other hand AucTeX clearly has some knowledge of all these marcos since *Tex-insert-macro* lists many of them among possible completions. Math macros are also defined in *LaTeX-math-default* in *latex.el*.

It seems that *font-latex.el* does not use this information. Is there a ``best practice'' to make *font-latex* learn all these keywords and fontify them appropriately?

Comment: Math should be fontified with `font-latex-math-face`, inline and display.  Are you sure you haven't some customization somewhere which tweaks this?

Comment: I was referring to fontifying macros in math mode, not the general math. E.g. consider `$a \leq b$`. a,b should be fontified using `font-latex-math-face`. What about `\leq`? it is a macro and should be detected and fontified as such.

Answer (score 5):

AUCTeX has built-in facilities for custom fontification.  Check the documentation, section [User-defined keyword classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros).  You have to set the variable `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`.  I did this in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq font-latex-user-keyword-classes
      '(("mathcmds"  (("frac" "{{"))  bold-italic              command)
        ("mathnoarg" ("leq")          font-lock-warning-face   noarg)))
```

to get this:

> [image]

Comment: How could one do such a thing but for a character rather than a command begining with a backlash. For example, it is clear how one would highlight \sum or \leq, but how could one highlight ∑ or ≤?